# How to disable a specific screen animation on cm 10.1.2?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, screen

On cm 10.0.0 I disabled the annoying "display off" "like old CRT" effect, but upgrading to 10.1.2 re-enabled it and I can't find anymore the display animation settings.

Can't find in the settings, couldn't find a new app, no idea where to search.

How can I do that?

Comment: Should be `Settings => Display => Screen-off animation`. Are you not seeing that option?

Comment: @eldarerathis exactly. I get brightness, wallpaper, rotation, sleep, daydream, font size and volume rocker wake.

Comment: What device, out of curiosity? I'm on a nightly build, not a stable one, but I had thought this setting was merged into the stable branches already. Maybe somehow it got omitted on your particular device's build (though that would be a little odd).

Comment: Nexus S (I guess that's "crespo"?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Apparently](http://forum.cyanogenmod.com/topic/75232-upgrade-to-1012-messed-up-many-things/), "This is not a user-configurable option right now".

I'm not sure if that's a general Android problem, or a specific cyanogenmod one. Totally clueless about *why*, of course.

Answer (score 0):

The missing setting was an error in 10.1. It is fixed now.

Go to `Settings` -> `Display` -> `Screen-off animation`